# How to take a dictionary of a substring set in Scala?

Tags: python, scala

I have a text file named "wordAndPronounciation.txt" which contains the following content. Expected output is the word as the key and any string after the word are concatenated together as the value.

```
DEFINE  D IH0 F AY1 N
PHOTOGRAPH  F OW1 T AH0 G R AE2 F
```

Input: `"wordAndPronounciation.txt"`

Output: `{"DEFINE": "DIH0FAY1N", "PHOTOGRAPH": "FOW1TAH0GRAE2F"}`

In Python, I can do this

```
def wordAndPronounciation(filename):
    table = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as x:
        for i in x:
            table[i.split(' ', 1)[0]] = ''.join(i.split()[1:])
    return table
```

Now how do I do this in Scala?

I tried this but I don't think it is correct.

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
        first, *middle, last = text.split()
        *middle = *middle.concat(last)
        table=Map(first -> *middle) }
```

One more thing, is there an easy way to reverse a string in Scala?
In python I can just do this, where `string = "CAT"` and you
`print(string[::-1])`

I tried this to reverse a string in Scala, 
`var reversedC = ("" /: string)((a, x) => x + a)`, but it is giving parameters error.

Comment: Please show us how far you got so that we have some idea what the problem is.

Comment: Hi @Anonymous, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself. Also, I would recommend you to take any basic **Scala** tutorial and to give a quick look to the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the rough equivalent of your Python code.

```
def wordAndPronounciation(fileName: String): Map[String,String] =
  io.Source.fromFile(fileName)                      //open file
           .getLines()                              //read file line-by-line
           .map(_.split("\\s+"))                    //spit on spaces
           .map(a => (a.head, a.tail.reduce(_+_)))  //create tuple
           .toMap                                   //as dictionary
```

P.S. `"reverse".reverse //res0: String = esrever`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if `*middle` is valid syntax in **Python** for storing a list of things. But I am sure it is not valid in **Scala**.
Second, your for is doing nothing. except if `table` is a mutable *var*, but in that case you are not updating its contents, but overwriting.

Your problem can be solved this way.

```
val map = (for {
  line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
  words = line.split(" ")
} yield words.head -> words.tail.mkString).toMap
// map: Map[String, String] = ...
```

Which is the same as:

```
val map =
  Source
    .fromFile(filename)
    .getLines
    .map(line => line.split(" "))
    .map { case Array(head, tail @ _*) => head -> tail.mkString }
    .toMap
```

Since a `for / yield` statement is just sugar syntax for `map`, `flatMap` & `filter` calls.

Finally, for reversing a String, just call the `reverse` method

```
"Hello, world!".reverse
// res0: String = "!dlrow ,olleH"
```